# How to move part of a svn repo to git

Tags: java, git, svn

I am trying to move a part of the Apache Aries project from svn to git. I only want to move the jpa subproject and its tags starting with the 2.0.0 tag.

This is the trunk url of jpa:
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/aries/trunk/jpa

This is one of the tags:
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/aries/tags/org.apache.aries.jpa-2.0.0/

In the end I would like to have a git repo with history of all files that are now below jpa on the svn trunk and the tags that look like above.

I was already able to get the jpa subdirectory and it history since the 2.0.0 tag which is the oldest I want to import:

```
git svn clone https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/aries/trunk/jpa --revision=1685808:HEAD
```

Now I need a way to add the tags in a way that they look like git tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The import works by using the git config below. So the core of it is to specify a correct path and pattern for the trunk and the tags.

I then ran `git svn fetch --revision=1685808:HEAD` with the revision of the first tag I wanted to import. This gave me the commits and the tags in git but the tags only were refs. So the last step was to create each tag in git from the respective ref like below:

```
git tag -a 2.6.1 refs/remotes/origin/tags/org.apache.aries.jpa-2.6.1 -m "Converting svn tag"
```

Config

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
url = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/aries
trunk = trunk/jpa
fetch = :refs/remotes/git-svn
tags = tags/org.apache.aries.jpa-*:refs/remotes/origin/tags/*
```